# Python script hangs up while calling external process

Tags: python, linux

I have written a Python script for acting as a simple GUI frontend. I need to get periodic updates from "wimaxc" process every five seconds. Here's what I have done:

```
import gtk.glade, re, thread, wimax_functions
from os import sys
from timer import RepeatTimer
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def RunCommand(command):
    p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    output = p.stdout.read()
    return output

class RoyalBengalWiMAX:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.glade.XML('gui.xml', 'window1')
        dic = {"on_window1_destroy" : self.quit,
               "on_information_click" : self.Set_Status,}
        self.window.signal_autoconnect(dic)
        self.Set_Status()

    def quit(self, obj):
        gtk.main_quit()
        sys.exit(1)

    def Get_Status(self):
        #Do Someting        

    def Set_Status(self):
        r = RepeatTimer(5.0, self.Get_Status, 10)
        r.start()

RoyalBengalWiMAX()
gtk.main()
```

I have used the RepeatTimer class from here: g-off.net/software/a-python-repeatable-threadingtimer-class

My script doesn't respond once I run it! Help required!

Comment: This code shouldn't compile, is this really everything? In particular, the empty `Get_Status()` method without a `pass` statement won't work.

Comment: Some other general comments- don't use old style classes when you can help it (prefer `class RoyalBengalWiMax(object):` over `class RoyalBengalWiMax:`), and *please* case properly- functions and methods should be lowercase and underscore-separated (`set_status` not `Set_Status`). PEP-8 has more details.

Comment: This is not the complete source, I have removed the very very long Get_Status method...

Comment: Do you update the GUI in another threads? try to use gobject.idle_add to wrap the function.